# scrollToLocatoin is not a function : react-native-swipe-list-view

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

I am trying to implement scroll to top function on tap of button to scroll on top position of swipe list view and trying to access method scrollToLocation from SectionList but I am not able to access it using the reference of SwipeListView. So I need help how to achieve it.Below is code from render function.

```
<SwipeListView
                    useSectionList={true}
                    sections={this.state.data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, section) => item.key }
                    renderItem={this.renderRow}
                    renderHiddenItem={this.renderHiddenItems}
                    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
                    rightOpenValue={-75}
                    stopRightSwipe={-75}
                    previewRowKey={'0'}
                    closeOnRowPress={true}
                    previewOpenValue={-40}
                    onRowDidOpen={this.onRowDidOpen}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                    bounces
                    disableRightSwipe={true}
                    enableEmptySections={false}
                    tension={20}
                    scrollsToTop={true}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.99}
                    onEndReached={() => {
                      this.setState({ isScrollToTopVisible: !this.state.isScrollToTopVisible })
                    }}
                    ref={(ref) => this.sectionListRef = ref }
    />
```

Code for scroll to top of list.

```
scrollToTop() {
   this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({ offset : 0, animated : true })
}
```

OS: iOS 12.1

React Native Version: v0.59.8

React-native-swipe-list-view Version: v2.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reference of listview : `listViewRef ={ ref => this.sectionListRef = ref }`

and and scrolltop function should be like :

```
scrollToTop() {
   this.sectionListRef.scrollToLocation({
            animated: true,
            itemIndex: 0,
            sectionIndex: 0,
            viewOffset: 0,
        });
}
```

Comment: I have made mistake to get reference of listView. Nice insight!!! Thanks

Comment: Is this still possible with react hooks?

Comment: Yes, it is possible